# Calculate the probability that a randomly chosen claim on this policy is processed in four hours or more

Tags: probability, actuarial-science

I'm not sure how to approach this question, can someone please help me?

An insurance policy is written to cover a loss X where X has density function
f(x) = (2/9)x for 0 ≤ x ≤ 3
       and 0 otherwise

The time (in hours) to process a claim of size x, where 0 ≤ x ≤ 3, is uniformly distributed
on the interval x to 4x. Calculate the probability that a randomly chosen claim on this policy is processed in four hours or more.

A. 0.425
B. 0.593
C. 0.666
D. 0.721
E. None of the above

Ive attempted the double integral:

1 to 3 and 4 to 4x (2/27) dy dx

since f(x,y) is 2/27 (1/3x times (2/9)x)

Comment: vicky, it's a good idea to provide your attempts on your questions, as it stands it's likely to be [closed]

Answer (score 1):

Use the law of total probability. Let $T$ be the time it takes to process a claim. Then $T\mid X=x\sim \text{Unif}(x, 4x)$. Note that $P(T\geq 4\mid X=x)=\frac{4x-4}{3x}=\frac{4(x-1)}{3x}$ for $1\leq x\leq 3$ and equal to zero otherwise.Hence
$$
P(T\geq 4)=\int P(T\geq 4\mid X=x)f_{X}(x)\, dx=\int_{1}^3\frac{4(x-1)}{3x}\frac{2}{9}x\, dx
$$
which you can compute.

Comment: can you explain why its from 1 to 3?